# Removing Unused Columns from a Bar Chart

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, bar-chart

I am creating a departmental bar chart that shows time frames for a set of tasks. Some departments share tasks, others are unique. I have the chart running except that I don't want all possible tasks listed for every department. I would only like to display those tasks that the department actually did.

Here is an example of the data (# in days):

```
IT  Pending         5
IT  In Process      8
CD  Pending         10
CD  1st Inspection  15
CD  Re-inspection    5
```

In this case I don't want to see "1st Inspection" or "Re-inspection" for IT because IT doesn't do that job nor do we want CD to have "In Process".

Is it possible to remove these unneeded series for a category?

The primary reason for asking this is because our data set is so large, it is nearly impossible to read the report. I think removing these unneeded columns would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must have been a long week for me. I switched how I was generating the graph and got what I wanted. My data was fine, I am now using the status for the category field and got it working.